# VHDL 2D Array Initialization using single Index

Tags: multidimensional-array, vhdl

```
type kelvin_Array is array(0 to 3, 0 to 1) of integer
signal array_int1 :kelvin_Array;
signal array_int2 :kelvin_Array;

begin
array_int1 (0,0) <= 5; --using 2 indexes
```

what I wanted is

```
array_int1(0) <= (5,3);
```

Please let me know how can I achieve this.

Regards,
Kelvin

Comment: A lot of synthesis tools still do not properly support multi-dimensional arrays. Preferably use jagged arrays, as Matthew suggests.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want a *single dimensional array* of a *single dimensional array of two integers*, eg:

```
  type matthew_Array is array(0 to 1) of integer;
  type matthew_Array_Array is array(0 to 9) of matthew_Array;

  signal array_int1 : matthew_Array_Array;

begin

  array_int1(0) <= (5,3);
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5Lz8

Comment: `integer_vector` is already part of VHDL-2008, so you could reuse it. I would also use `type integer_vector_vector is array (natural range <>) of integer_vector;` and instantiate `signal array_int1 : integer_vector_vector(0 to 9)(0 to 1);`

Comment: Yes - `integer_vector` could be useful, but only if you can use VHDL-2008.